# how to change carla map road slope

Tags: carla

I tried to change an existing [CARLA simulator](https://carla.org/) map road slope like San Francico downhill intersection. Can not find an editor for it. Would anyone suggest a right tool to do it? a tutorial link will be even better. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to build carla (not the precompile version), and the editor for maps is unreal engine. So in the build process you will have to install also unreal engine (the installation steps are already provided in carla tutorial). You can find find the link to build carla and install unreal engine here : https://carla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_linux/.

When all the prerequisites are install, you launched unreal engine and select the map you want to edit, and at the end you save all you modifications. you will then need to generate a compiled version of carla simulator with your customized map.

Here is the link to build carla and unreal : https://carla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_linux/   (you may need to additional steps for unreal engine).

On the same tutorial page, you can find on the left side links to maps customizaton : https://carla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tuto_M_custom_map_overview/#customization

Answer (score 0):

I think Repli5 could offer a solution to this problem. We're building WorldGenerator, a software that helps to easily create and edit 3D simulation environments. The virtual worlds created using WorldGenerator can be used in Carla and other simulators. You can procedurally edit roads, slopes, assets - include deformations as necessary etc.

Worth checking out if you believe it could provide some benefits to your workflow with Carla!

[www.repli5.com](http://www.repli5.com)

Hope it helps!